# Как скопировать с папки appdata/local/temp?

Tags: c++, qt

```
std::string Import::getTempFile()
{
    // получаем имя временного файла
    QTemporaryFile file;
    if (file.open()) 
    {
        return file.fileName().toStdString();
    }
    return "";
}
```

1 - получаю временный файл, куда будет сортироваться

```
std::string tempFileName = getTempFile();
```

2 - сортирую содержимое

```
QProcess process;
process.start("sort " + inputFile + " /O " + outputFile);
process.waitForFinished();
```

3 - копирую файл

```
std::string commandCopyFile = "copy /y \"" + tempFileName + "\"" + " \"" + _fileName + "\"";
process.start(QString::fromStdString(commandCopyFile));
process.waitForFinished();
```

3 - удаляю временный файл

```
std::string commandDeleteFile = "del " + tempFileName;
process.start(QString::fromStdString(commandDeleteFile));
```

я столкнулся с такой проблемой: я не могу заменить файл (шаг 3). Пробовал через консоль. Консоль выдавала: не может найти такой файл. Видимо временный файл нельзя скопировать или я скорее всего не правильно что то делаю.

Comment: "Консоль выдавала: не может найти такой файл." - а этот файл существует?

Comment: да, конечно, ради интереса я его скопировал в другую папку и через консоль скопировал в нужный файл. Может быть такое, что не хватает прав?

Comment: При копировании вы имя файла помещаете в кавычки, при удалении - нет. В нем (имени) точно нет какого-нибудь пробела?...

Comment: До удаления я еще не дошел, мне бы копирование сделать. И удаление тоже не работает. Нету пробелов. все сплошняком везде. Путь примерно такой:
copy /Y "C:/Users/filad/AppData/Local/Temp/Iasdg.IBjOmj" "C:/Users/filad/Desktop/kjlkjlkjklj.csv"